# Как сделать чтобы текст уходил за границу div слева

Tags: html, css

Обычное поведение текста, если он больше чем размер ограничивающего `div` и добавлены свойства   `white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;` - текст выходит за границу `div` **справа** и исчезает.

Как сделать чтобы текст при превышении размера `div` уходил и за его **левую** границу? А правая часть текста (конец предложения) оставалась у левой границы `div`.

Т.е. чтобы если предложение не помещается в отведенное ему место - обрезалось бы его начало а не конец?

---edit---

В общем мне нужно чтобы 2 предложения отображались из центра в разные стороны (влево и вправо) и исчезали за границами div. Div- динамичной ширины, при ее изменении оба предложения одинаково обрезаются.
Должно быть примерно так:

`|...row olleh .ecnetnes elpmis si sihT||This is simple sentence. hello wor...|`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не уверен, что есть безкостыльный метод для подобного, поэтому вот:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, porro!</span>
</div>
```

### UPD

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div::before,
div::after {
  content: '...';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

div::after {
  right: 0;
}

div span:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 51%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div span:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 51%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, porro!</span>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, porro!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 Помечаю как решенный вопрос, потому что действительно работает. К сожалению, в моем случае, нужно что-то другое.

Comment: @FFire уточните вопрос, попробую решить

Comment: Добавил уточнения в вопрос.

Comment: @FFire обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
.div {
width: calc(100% * 2 / 3);//пример
height: 400px;//пример
overflow: hidden;
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

В целом вот так

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. возможно, стоит привести пример использования. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]